# How do I create bar chart/graph using the Graphics class and fill.rect?

Tags: graphics, graph

```
    /* Written by Brandon Colchin */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Bar extends JApplet
{
   public void paint (Graphics x)
   {
      super.paint( x);

        //declare variables
        int Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri;

        //create scanner
        System.out.println("Please enter the unrealistic amount of math problems you do each day");
        Scanner bar = new Scanner(System.in);
        Mon = bar.nextInt();
        Tues = bar.nextInt();
        Wed = bar.nextInt();
        Thurs = bar.nextInt();
        Fri = bar.nextInt();


        //create edges
        x.drawLine(50, 50, 50, 300);
        x.drawLine(50, 300, 350, 300);

        //label edges
        x.drawString("100", 25, 60);
        x.drawString("90", 30, 85);
        x.drawString("80", 30, 110);
        x.drawString("70", 30, 135);
        x.drawString("60", 30, 160);
        x.drawString("50", 30, 185);
        x.drawString("40", 30, 210);
        x.drawString("30", 30, 235);
        x.drawString("20", 30, 260);
        x.drawString("10", 30, 290);
        x.drawString("Mon", 65, 315);
        x.drawString("Tues", 130, 315);
        x.drawString("Wed", 195, 315);
        x.drawString("Thurs", 260, 315);
        x.drawString("Fri", 325, 315);


        //draw bars
        x.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        x.fillRect( 60, (Mon), 40, Mon );
        x.setColor(Color.RED);
        x.fillRect( 125, (Tues), 40, Tues );
        x.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        x.fillRect( 190, (Wed), 40, Wed );
        x.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        x.fillRect( 255, (Thurs), 40, Thurs );
        x.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        x.fillRect( 320, (Fri), 40, Fri );`
```

The output is a graph with 100-10 on the left and Mon-Fri on the bottom and 5 rectangles.

This is for a programming class and the requirements are: Axes must be on left and bottom of graph, the 5 numbers for the 5 bars must be user inputed.

I do not know what factors to multiply the y point and the height by to make the graph start at the corresponding number on the left of the graph (ex if user inputs 60, the graph height will match up with the 60 to the left of the graph and the bottom will stop at the x-axis edge)

Also when I am prompted to enter in 5 numbers after running the program, it makes me enter 10 numbers, even though I only have nextInt 5 times. What is weird is that the first 5 numbers inputed do NOTHING and only the last 5 numbers are used for Mon - Fri.

Any help needed